# how to display a span with JS in ionic

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

I have tried so much just to display a simple variable in ionic and it's not working? can anyone tell me what's wrong?

I have displayed both ways in the code snippet... and for the life of me i can't figure out what i'm doing wrong?

```js
localforage.setItem('milk', '0.0', callbackFunction);

var coffee = localStorage.getItem("coffee") ?  localStorage.getItem("coffee") : 0.0;

function milkIt(){
  milk = milk += 1;
}

function coffeeIt(){
  coffee = coffee += 1;
  document.getElementById("coffee").innerHTML = coffee;

}

var coffee = localStorage.getItem("coffee") ?  localStorage.getItem("coffee") : 0.0;
var totalCoffee = localStorage.getItem("totalCoffee") ? localStorage.getItem("totalCoffee") : 0.0;

var coffeePs = localStorage.getItem("coffeePs") ? localStorage.getItem("coffeePs") : 0;
var cookRate = localStorage.getItem("cookRate") ?  localStorage.getItem("cookRate") : 1.0;

$("#coffeeButton").click(function(e) {

    var obj = $("#clone").clone();
    var img = $("#myImg").clone(); 

    $("body").append(obj);
    $("body").append(img);

    obj.html("+"+ cookRate);
    coffee += cookRate;
    totalCoffee += cookRate;
    document.getElementById("coffee").innerHTML = prettify(coffee);
    document.getElementById("totalCoffee").innerHTML = prettify(totalCoffee);

    obj.css('position','absolute'); 
    obj.css('z-index', '2');
    img.css('position','absolute');
    img.show();

    obj.offset({left: e.pageX-10, top: e.pageY-80});
    img.offset({left: e.pageX-10, top: e.pageY-50});

    obj.animate({"top": "-=80px"}, 1000, "linear", function() {
        $(this).remove();
    }); 
    img.animate({"top": "-=80px"}, 1000, "linear", function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });

});
```

```css
.button{
 display: block;
}

#coffeeButton{
 cursor: pointer; cursor: hand; background: #5EFF8F; border-radius: 7px; margin: 5px; padding: 20px; font: bold 30px Tahoma; text-align: left;
 -webkit-touch-callout: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; -user-select: none;
}
#clone{
 font-size: 1.5em;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none; 
 -moz-user-select: none; 
 -ms-user-select: none; 
 -user-select: none;

}
```

```html
<div class = "col">
  Milk = <span id = "milk">0.0</span>

</div>

<div class = "col">
  Coffee = <span id = "coffee">0.0</span>
</div>


<div class = "row">
  <div class = "col"><button on-tap="milkIt()" class="button button-balanced button-block button-large">Milk Cow</button></div>
  <div class = "col"><button on-tap="coffeeIt()" class="button button-assertive button-block button-large">Sell Milk</button></div> 
         
</div>


<div id = "coffeeButton">Make Coffee <br /><span id = "cookRate">1</span> Per Click</div>Coffee = <span id = "coffee">0.0</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting at the top:

```
localforage.setItem('milk', '0.0', callbackFunction);
```

callbackFunction is not defined anywhere.

```
milk = milk += 1;
```

"milk +=1;" is the same as "milk = milk+1;", so your line means "milk = milk = milk+1;"

```
var coffee = localStorage.getItem("coffee") ?  localStorage.getItem("coffee") : 0.0;
```

This line is repeated.  You can only define the variable once.  Was this supposed to be totalCoffee?

Stopping there.  Good luck.

Comment: oh thanks for replying, i thought callbackfunction was a function of localforage, thanks for that now. oh i will fix the milk ling, originally it was milk = milk =+ milkRate howver i removed it for testing and dammit lol and lastly no that line is not repeated, first it checks if there is a value then it sets it to 0 if it does not exist.

thanks again hopefully this will fix it.